Docker Desktop - WSL update failed
Currently I use Docker Desktop 4.32.0 version on Windows-10, I updated to new version, after this Docker Engine Stopped Running and gave error wsl update failed: update failed: updating wsl: exit code: 4294967295: running WSL command wsl.exe C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe --update --web-download. I tried wsl --update and wsl --update --web-download but both shows Installing: Windows Subsystem for Linux The provided package is already installed, and reinstallation of the package was blocked. Check the AppXDeployment-Server event log for details. this message in windows power shell. I downloaded msi file and executed still docker engine gives same error. I got some file permission error so updated docker desktop, but wsl 2 is not getting updated. Please anyone help me.

earlier I had 4.29 version only, I got some file permission error, so updated to 4.32, here wsl 2 is not getting updated

No need to downgrade your Docker Desktop. There is just something wrong with the default installation of Wsl.exe.
Option 1: A quick fix 

Run wsl --update OR wsl --update --web-download

This work for many but not for me. What worked for me is option 2
Option 2: A clean install 

Make sure there are no pending Windows Updates (thanks @Nik)
Optionally, you can uninstall "Docker Desktop". There are people who made this work without uninstalling Docker Desktop. (thanks @alfred-luu)
Turn off "Windows Subsystem for Linux" in "Turn Windows features on or off" (I've restarted, but you may not need to)



Install the latest release of Wsl here https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases/ (or just run wsl --install or wsl.exe --install)
Run wsl --status to confirm installation.
Install "Docker Desktop" again


Also, make sure:

You don't have pending windows updates. Go to Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update and ensure your system is fully updated.
You run wsl --install within a C:\WINDOWS\System32 directory.


Works like a charm, I did step 3 and 4 and solved my problem, no need to uninstall docker desktop because it was fresh installed in my case.

Making sure there are no updates on Windows worked for me. Goto Settings> Update and Security > Windows Update, make sure it's green and it says you're up to date. and Start Docker again.

Using wsl --update command worked for me

This should be the answer!

I got the solution from Docker Docs AI, it tells to install WSL v2.2.4.0 ,I installed that from it's github page WSL v2.2.4.0 download, I didnt downgrade to Docker Desktop 4.29. Now in my computer Docker Desktop 4.33 works fine.

The answer can be better if the Github page is linked

@AbdulrazaqHaroon https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases/download/2.2.4/wsl.2.2.4.0.x64.msi

Updating WSL manually by downloading updater worked for me. Thanks

I had the same problem until I upgraded the Windows system using the
Windows Upgrade Tool.
When I look at the error logs, it has two errors because of the execution of the wsl instruction:
wsl --version
wsl --update --web-download

I don't know why when my windows version is 21H2 it can't be work.  But it doesn't matter, this problem is solved.

Update Windows to the latest version.
I had the same problem.
I reinstalled both wsl and docker, but nothing helped except updating Windows.
